# How can a variable be used to set the src of an image in a production Ember app?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have some images in my Ember app that are static files declared in ember-cli-build.js.

When the app is used in production, the URLs of the images will change from `/icons/icon.png` to something like `/icons/icon-9ace8daf640d474c5472a54df98a4299.png`. So this:

```
<img src="/icons/icon.png">
```

becomes:

```
<img src="/icons/icon-9ace8daf640d474c5472a54df98a4299.png">
```

How don't know why this happens (browser cache?). This breaks my images where the src comes from a variable. For example:

```
<img src="{{imgURL}}">
```

If imgURL equals `/icons/icon.png`, then the browser will be dealing with `<img src="/icons/icon.png">` and the request will fail because the URL leads to nothing. In development everything works as expected.

How can a variable be used to set the src of an image in a production Ember app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of [broccoli-asset-rev](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev), which is used in `ember-cli` by default.

First, usually its not a good idea to have a static URL to an image in the `.js` file at all. It's mostly a better solution to keep it in the template.

However, to answer your question, you have multiple possible solution.

1. Don't use `broccoli-asset-rev` at all. For this just remove it from your `package.json`, and the files won't get renamed anymore.
2. Add the images you want to use from `.js` to the `exclude` array.
3. Use the generated `assetMap.json` to get the new file name.

To make your best decision you need to understand why `broccoli-asset-rev` is useful.

The idea is basically that you can cache your files except your `index.html` forever on the client and/or proxies, and just use a unique URL for each version. However if your server does not sent the `Expires` header at all, there is no benefit in using `broccoli-asset-rev`.

Comment: In your 2nd paragraph, what JS file are you talking about? Why is it a bad idea to have static URLs there?

Comment: How can I access that assetMap.json file?

Comment: Here is [some useful info](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev/issues/24) about the issue